# List number of rows per field value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

database/SQL novice here.

I have a table with a column called, for example, "EmployeeID". I want a query that will, for each distinct employeeID, return the number of rows that have that as their ID. I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do and someone will know how to help!

I don't think it should matter, but just in case, I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Looking at the answer, a lot of people uses DISTINCT. Is there any advantage in using it in this case ? Is it faster ?

Comment: @David Only one answer uses `DISTINCT` it isn't required as the semantics of the query mean that only 1 row per Employee will be returned.

Comment: I know what DISTINCT means. My point was this : Won't it generate useless computation to use a DISTINCT when not requied. 
When I commented, there was 2 if not 3 answer with DISINCT. Seems like some were modified since.

Comment: @David A quick check in SQL2008 for this simple query shows that it generates identical query plans. I agree with the general thrust of your comment though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple SQL

```
select EmployeeId,count(*)
from YourTable
Group by EmployeeId
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the "group by" keyword. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @josephj1989 what about showing the rest of the fields. e.g select  * , EmployeeId,count(*)
from YourTable
Group by EmployeeId

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.employeeid,
         COUNT(*) AS num_instances
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.employeeid
```

COUNT is an aggregate function, which requires the use of a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT employeeID, COUNT(employeeID) FROM Employees GROUP BY employeeID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) AS RowCount, EmployeeID
FROM table
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeID,
COUNT(employeeID) AS [Count]
FROM Employees
GROUP BY employeeID
```

Comment: Don't need DISTINCT when grouping by the value.